# measuring Hyperledger Composer performance using Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-caliper

Is it possible to measure Hyperledger composer network performance which runs on Hyperledger fabric using Hyperledger Caliper framework?
If yes can you guide me how can I change the configuration to connect Caliper to running Hyperledger composer network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use composer rest server to enable rest api endpoints, you can always use apache meter to test out the latency of your system.

Answer (score 7):

Hyperledger Caliper is a blockchain benchmark framework to measure performance of multiple blockchain solutions.

I think the below links help you a lot.

[Hyperledger Caliper Setup](https://github.com/hyperledger/caliper)

[Hyperledger Caliper](https://www.hyperledger.org/projects/caliper)