# Hyperledger Composer - Is ready for production?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i'm wondering if Hyperledger Composer is ready for production.
Does anyone know where I can find documentation about the performances of Composer?

***UPDATE:*** here an important message from Hyperledger Composer Community
https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is production ready. It installs native NodeJS smart contracts as 'chaincode' on the runtime peers of the Fabric blockchain, just like you'll have previously seen with 'Go' 'chaincode'. See release notes for more info https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/releases

As for performance - see this thread [measuring Hyperledger Composer performance using Hyperledger Caliper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49583406/measuring-hyperledger-composer-performance-using-hyperledger-caliper)  - you can perform your own tests using the instructions here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/docs/Composer.html (every environment is different).

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing so I conducted a simple experiment. I took an existing microservice and replaced the MySql, Redis, and Cassandra parts with API calls to a business network built with Hyperledger Composer. I ran a load test on both microservices and compared the performance results. All of the assets used in this experiment is open source and you can read more about this experiment in this [Evaluating Hyperledger Composer](https://www.infoq.com/articles/evaluating-hyperledger-composer) article.

Answer (score 0):

As this [website](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/index.html) us tells, it is ready to use. Also there you will find a documentation and `GitHub` project